# Exclude posts w/ specific post_meta on Rest API endpoint

Tags: posts, rest-api, endpoints

So WordPress offers the default Rest API endpoint, which is: `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` which pulls in all the posts.

Is there a way to configure and modify the existing `/wp/v2/posts` endpoint to exclude posts that have a post_meta of `global_post`?

Answer (score 2):

### Caveat

From [the REST API docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#important-note-about-changing-responses):

> Changing or removing data from core REST API endpoint responses can break plugins or WordPress core behavior, and should be avoided wherever possible.

That said, there's a [`rest_post_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) filter (well, `rest_{$this->post_type}_query`) that will let you modify the `WP_Query` that's grabbing your posts, so you should be able to add a `meta_query` to the query.

eg:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'wpse405394_remove_global_posts', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Removes the "global_post" posts from the REST API.
 *
 * @param  array           $args    The WP_Query arguments.
 * @param  WP_REST_Request $request The REST request.
 * @return array                    The filtered $args.
 */
function wpse405394_remove_global_posts( $args, $request ) {
    if ( empty( $args['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'] = array();
    }
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'     => 'global_post',
        'value'   => true,
        'compare' => '!=', 
    ); 
    return $args;
}
```

**This code is not tested, and may break things in your site.** A *lot* of things use the REST API under the hood (eg: the block editor). Test thoroughly.

### References

- [`rest_{$this->post_type}_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/)
- [`WP_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)
- [`WP_Meta_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query)

Comment: Thanks @Pat, I did not know it can be that impactful, would it be better to create a custom endpoint and then do the same that `wp/v2/posts` is doing, excluding the post_meta posts?

Comment: How would this be possible to be built? Pull in all posts excluding post_meta 'global_post' posts, on the custom endpoint.

Comment: I have this other question posted if you can take a peak at it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/405385/wordpress-rest-api-get-all-posts-based-on-post-meta-on-custom-endpoint